# Prestashop admin panel modules and service link not work

Tags: e-commerce, prestashop, cart

Everyone, I have a prestashop site www.nepick.com it's going fine but when i login in my back end  and click modules and services than it's automatically redirected to index page. I  tried 100+ but I face same issue please help me.

Comment: Please can you add more technical informations? Was it working before? What has changed since? Did you try on different browser? ...

Comment: Yes. I tried mozila and ie also. But I face same problem earlier I changed my hosting server after that I face this problem

Comment: I've the same issue with Prestashop 1.7.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

it takes some tweaking with nginx bit it works. Do check out the sample nginx.configuration file at:

https://github.com/MattLoyeD/Prestashop-Nginx

The main issue is that it uses /adminXXX/index.php/product/... urls and those need to be directed to adminXXX/index.php?...

P.S. If you build on that add "attribute" and "feature" to the list of modules in that list of symfony names as well, as they are needed but currently missing.